# How can I send keys to inactive DirectX "ePSXe" window?

Tags: c#, directx, sendmessage, postmessage

I need to send a key to an inactive "ePSXe" window using C#. I got the handle of the window using Spy++, but when I used this code to send key "x", I got nothing. What should I do?

I tried different values of `Msg` as `0x0100`, `0x0101` and `0x0102`, but nothing worked. I also tried `SendMessage` and the results were the same.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private void Send_X(IntPtr p)
{
    PostMessage(p, 0x0100, (IntPtr)Keys.X, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

I expect the window to respond to my key. I managed only to send F keys "F1, F2..", but not letter keys.

```
SendMessage(p, 0x0100, (IntPtr)Keys.F4, IntPtr.Zero);
SendMessage(p, 0x0101, (IntPtr)Keys.F4, IntPtr.Zero);
```

---

I think sending to an inactive game application is not easy, however this solution helped me a lot, but I have to focus ePSXe.
[Sending keys to a DirectX Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138778/sending-keys-to-a-directx-game).

I am still looking for a solution that can send to an inactive game window.

Comment: If your above comment is important to your question, please [edit] it in otherwise it may be removed.

Comment: Why not use SetForegroundWindow(p) to bring the window to the top so that it has input focus and then SendKeys.SendWait("X")?

Comment: I am currently using this `SetForegroundWindow(p)` as an imperfect solution. My ultimate goal is to send keys without the need to bring the window to foreground as I want to manipulate multiple windows simultaneously.

Comment: How did you get the handle? Direct copy from Spy++? [`FindWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww)?

Comment: Using this `handle = Process.GetProcessesByName("ePSXe")[0].MainWindowHandle;`, then I confirm it with Spy++.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process P = ...get process; 
IntPtr whandle= P.MainWindowHandle;
PostMessage(whandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)(Keys.X), IntPtr.Zero);
```

It works if you have `MainWindowHandle` of that process, otherwise not.

Comment: The window handle 'sr values are not stable, it will probably change every run of your target app.

And you have to find top window of that process. otherwise it your message will not get process

And also check that your  window handle is not IntPtr.zero

Comment: I already know this. I got the handle and have no doubt about it, but this is not the problem as I'm able to send F4 successfully. The problem is with letters keys.