# Repeat my pressed key foreach my background DirectX games

Tags: c#, directx, sendkeys, keystroke

I tried this code, but it works only for foreground process (I need background).

I want other accounts to make the same move while I'm playing from main account.

I tried `PostMessage`, but it is not working for me because just working on chat window in game (I can't move, jump or anything).

Note: Other accounts are not foreground.

```
private GlobalKeyboardHook _globalKeyboardHook;
InputSimulator si = new InputSimulator();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
    _globalKeyboardHook.KeyboardPressed += OnKeyPressed;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
const UInt32 WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
const int VK_SPACE = 0x20;
int sayi = 0;
IntPtr hWnd = (IntPtr)null;
private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs e)
{
    ++sayi;
    if (sayi == 1)
    {
        if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 107)
        {
            Process MainProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Trove").FirstOrDefault();
            hWnd = MainProcess.MainWindowHandle;
        }
        else
        {
            Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process P in processList)
            {
                if (P.ProcessName.Equals("Trove"))
                {
                    if (P.MainWindowHandle != hWnd)
                    {
                        edit = P.MainWindowHandle;
                        Keyboard.SendKey(Keyboard.DirectXKeyStrokes.DIK_W, false, Keyboard.InputType.Keyboard); //i need send to "edit".
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sayi = 0;
}
```

Im using this class. its working but i need to send key press by hWnd(process).

```
/// <summary>
    /// My own question as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138778/sending-keys-to-a-directx-game
    /// http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html
    /// </summary>
    public class Keyboard
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum InputType
        {
            Mouse = 0,
            Keyboard = 1,
            Hardware = 2
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum KeyEventF
        {
            KeyDown = 0x0000,
            ExtendedKey = 0x0001,
            KeyUp = 0x0002,
            Unicode = 0x0004,
            Scancode = 0x0008,
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, Input[] pInputs, int cbSize);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();

        /// <summary>
        /// DirectX key list collected out from the gamespp.com list by me.
        /// </summary>
        public enum DirectXKeyStrokes
        {
            DIK_ESCAPE = 0x01,
            DIK_1 = 0x02,
            DIK_2 = 0x03,
            DIK_3 = 0x04,
            DIK_4 = 0x05,
            DIK_5 = 0x06,
            DIK_6 = 0x07,
            DIK_7 = 0x08,
            DIK_8 = 0x09,
            DIK_9 = 0x0A,
            DIK_0 = 0x0B,
            DIK_MINUS = 0x0C,
            DIK_EQUALS = 0x0D,
            DIK_BACK = 0x0E,
            DIK_TAB = 0x0F,
            DIK_Q = 0x10,
            DIK_W = 0x11,
            DIK_E = 0x12,
            DIK_R = 0x13,
            DIK_T = 0x14,
            DIK_Y = 0x15,
            DIK_U = 0x16,
            DIK_I = 0x17,
            DIK_O = 0x18,
            DIK_P = 0x19,
            DIK_LBRACKET = 0x1A,
            DIK_RBRACKET = 0x1B,
            DIK_RETURN = 0x1C,
            DIK_LCONTROL = 0x1D,
            DIK_A = 0x1E,
            DIK_S = 0x1F,
            DIK_D = 0x20,
            DIK_F = 0x21,
            DIK_G = 0x22,
            DIK_H = 0x23,
            DIK_J = 0x24,
            DIK_K = 0x25,
            DIK_L = 0x26,
            DIK_SEMICOLON = 0x27,
            DIK_APOSTROPHE = 0x28,
            DIK_GRAVE = 0x29,
            DIK_LSHIFT = 0x2A,
            DIK_BACKSLASH = 0x2B,
            DIK_Z = 0x2C,
            DIK_X = 0x2D,
            DIK_C = 0x2E,
            DIK_V = 0x2F,
            DIK_B = 0x30,
            DIK_N = 0x31,
            DIK_M = 0x32,
            DIK_COMMA = 0x33,
            DIK_PERIOD = 0x34,
            DIK_SLASH = 0x35,
            DIK_RSHIFT = 0x36,
            DIK_MULTIPLY = 0x37,
            DIK_LMENU = 0x38,
            DIK_SPACE = 0x39,
            DIK_CAPITAL = 0x3A,
            DIK_F1 = 0x3B,
            DIK_F2 = 0x3C,
            DIK_F3 = 0x3D,
            DIK_F4 = 0x3E,
            DIK_F5 = 0x3F,
            DIK_F6 = 0x40,
            DIK_F7 = 0x41,
            DIK_F8 = 0x42,
            DIK_F9 = 0x43,
            DIK_F10 = 0x44,
            DIK_NUMLOCK = 0x45,
            DIK_SCROLL = 0x46,
            DIK_NUMPAD7 = 0x47,
            DIK_NUMPAD8 = 0x48,
            DIK_NUMPAD9 = 0x49,
            DIK_SUBTRACT = 0x4A,
            DIK_NUMPAD4 = 0x4B,
            DIK_NUMPAD5 = 0x4C,
            DIK_NUMPAD6 = 0x4D,
            DIK_ADD = 0x4E,
            DIK_NUMPAD1 = 0x4F,
            DIK_NUMPAD2 = 0x50,
            DIK_NUMPAD3 = 0x51,
            DIK_NUMPAD0 = 0x52,
            DIK_DECIMAL = 0x53,
            DIK_F11 = 0x57,
            DIK_F12 = 0x58,
            DIK_F13 = 0x64,
            DIK_F14 = 0x65,
            DIK_F15 = 0x66,
            DIK_KANA = 0x70,
            DIK_CONVERT = 0x79,
            DIK_NOCONVERT = 0x7B,
            DIK_YEN = 0x7D,
            DIK_NUMPADEQUALS = 0x8D,
            DIK_CIRCUMFLEX = 0x90,
            DIK_AT = 0x91,
            DIK_COLON = 0x92,
            DIK_UNDERLINE = 0x93,
            DIK_KANJI = 0x94,
            DIK_STOP = 0x95,
            DIK_AX = 0x96,
            DIK_UNLABELED = 0x97,
            DIK_NUMPADENTER = 0x9C,
            DIK_RCONTROL = 0x9D,
            DIK_NUMPADCOMMA = 0xB3,
            DIK_DIVIDE = 0xB5,
            DIK_SYSRQ = 0xB7,
            DIK_RMENU = 0xB8,
            DIK_HOME = 0xC7,
            DIK_UP = 0xC8,
            DIK_PRIOR = 0xC9,
            DIK_LEFT = 0xCB,
            DIK_RIGHT = 0xCD,
            DIK_END = 0xCF,
            DIK_DOWN = 0xD0,
            DIK_NEXT = 0xD1,
            DIK_INSERT = 0xD2,
            DIK_DELETE = 0xD3,
            DIK_LWIN = 0xDB,
            DIK_RWIN = 0xDC,
            DIK_APPS = 0xDD,
            DIK_BACKSPACE = DIK_BACK,
            DIK_NUMPADSTAR = DIK_MULTIPLY,
            DIK_LALT = DIK_LMENU,
            DIK_CAPSLOCK = DIK_CAPITAL,
            DIK_NUMPADMINUS = DIK_SUBTRACT,
            DIK_NUMPADPLUS = DIK_ADD,
            DIK_NUMPADPERIOD = DIK_DECIMAL,
            DIK_NUMPADSLASH = DIK_DIVIDE,
            DIK_RALT = DIK_RMENU,
            DIK_UPARROW = DIK_UP,
            DIK_PGUP = DIK_PRIOR,
            DIK_LEFTARROW = DIK_LEFT,
            DIK_RIGHTARROW = DIK_RIGHT,
            DIK_DOWNARROW = DIK_DOWN,
            DIK_PGDN = DIK_NEXT,

            // Mined these out of nowhere.
            DIK_LEFTMOUSEBUTTON = 0x100,
            DIK_RIGHTMOUSEBUTTON = 0x101,
            DIK_MIDDLEWHEELBUTTON = 0x102,
            DIK_MOUSEBUTTON3 = 0x103,
            DIK_MOUSEBUTTON4 = 0x104,
            DIK_MOUSEBUTTON5 = 0x105,
            DIK_MOUSEBUTTON6 = 0x106,
            DIK_MOUSEBUTTON7 = 0x107,
            DIK_MOUSEWHEELUP = 0x108,
            DIK_MOUSEWHEELDOWN = 0x109,
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a directx key.
        /// http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <param name="KeyUp"></param>
        /// <param name="inputType"></param>
        public static void SendKey(DirectXKeyStrokes key, bool KeyUp, InputType inputType)
        {
            uint flagtosend;
            if (KeyUp)
            {
                flagtosend = (uint)(KeyEventF.KeyUp | KeyEventF.Scancode);
            }
            else
            {
                flagtosend = (uint)(KeyEventF.KeyDown | KeyEventF.Scancode);
            }

            Input[] inputs =
            {
        new Input
        {
            type = (int) inputType,
            u = new InputUnion
            {
                ki = new KeyboardInput
                {
                    wVk = 0,
                    wScan = (ushort) key,
                    dwFlags = flagtosend,
                    dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo()
                }
            }
        }
    };
            SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Input)));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a directx key.
        /// http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <param name="KeyUp"></param>
        /// <param name="inputType"></param>
        public static void SendKey(ushort key, bool KeyUp, InputType inputType)
        {
            uint flagtosend;
            if (KeyUp)
            {
                flagtosend = (uint)(KeyEventF.KeyUp | KeyEventF.Scancode);
            }
            else
            {
                flagtosend = (uint)(KeyEventF.KeyDown | KeyEventF.Scancode);
            }

            Input[] inputs =
            {
        new Input
        {
            type = (int) inputType,
            u = new InputUnion
            {
                ki = new KeyboardInput
                {
                    wVk = 0,
                    wScan = key,
                    dwFlags = flagtosend,
                    dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo()
                }
            }
        }
    };

            SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Input)));
        }

        public struct Input
        {
            public int type;
            public InputUnion u;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct InputUnion
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] public readonly MouseInput mi;
            [FieldOffset(0)] public KeyboardInput ki;
            [FieldOffset(0)] public readonly HardwareInput hi;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MouseInput
        {
            public readonly int dx;
            public readonly int dy;
            public readonly uint mouseData;
            public readonly uint dwFlags;
            public readonly uint time;
            public readonly IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct KeyboardInput
        {
            public ushort wVk;
            public ushort wScan;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public readonly uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct HardwareInput
        {
            public readonly uint uMsg;
            public readonly ushort wParamL;
            public readonly ushort wParamH;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I did something like this when I was developing a bot for a game, and it only took inputs when it was the active window. If you do not want to change the foreground window all the time (and have timing problems), you can try tricking the game to think it is a foreground window (BE AWARE OF ANTI-CHEATS DETECTING THIS).

So what I did was to hook the following methods in the game:

[GetFocus()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getfocus)

[GetForegroundWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow)

[GetActiveWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getactivewindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

And replace all these functions with functions that return the game's window's handle. This way whenever the game checks if it is active or not with these functions, it will think it is the active window. But there is still a problem, when you activate another window (and the game was active before that), the OS sends a deactivate message to the game, so it won't care about anything (even when the methods are overridden). So after sending your game to the background, you manually have to send the WM_ACTIVATE, WM_SETFOCUS and other messages to the game (to make it think it was activated again). You can find these messages with Spy++, and just copy the behaviour from there.

After you "reactivated" your game manually aka sending the messages (be careful not to activate it by clicking on it, since when you click to something else, it would be deactivated again), it should process the key messages sent by you.

**EDIT:** Alternatively you could edit the game's [WindowProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v%3Dvs.85)) which processes the messages and make it ignore the deactivate message, instead of sending the activations manually. But I have no idea how to do this, and never tried it. The first method worked for me.

**EDIT**: So the basic code sample:

First you need the DLL to inject into the process:

```
HWND WINAPI MyGetActiveWindow()
{
    return Main_window_handle;
}
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall NativeInjectionEntryPoint(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO* inRemoteInfo);

void __stdcall NativeInjectionEntryPoint(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO* inRemoteInfo)
{
    Main_window_handle = GET_MAIN_WINDOW_HANDLE_THE_WAY_YOU_LIKE;

    HOOK_TRACE_INFO Hook_active = { NULL };

    NTSTATUS Result_active = LhInstallHook(
        GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("user32")), "GetActiveWindow"),
        MyGetActiveWindow,
        NULL,
        &Hook_active);

    if (FAILED(Result_active))
    {
        std::terminate();
    }

    ULONG ACLEntries[1] = { 0 };

    LhSetExclusiveACL(ACLEntries, 1, &Hook_active);

    return;
}
```

You compile this to a DLL and inject it the way you like to your program.

To activate the program you have to send the following messages (probably less is enough, i used all these.):

```
    SendMessage(hwnd, 0x001C, 1, 0);
    SendMessage(hwnd, 0x0086, 1, 0);
    SendMessage(hwnd, 0x0006, 2, 0);
    SendMessage(hwnd, 0x0007, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This looks interesting, can you provide a complete sample of the code?

Comment: You can set up the hooks with https://easyhook.github.io/ , you basically just have to replace some words in the remote hooking example.

And you can send the messages with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/sendmessage--postmessage--and-related-functions functions.

I'll be able to share some code only later, but this should not be too hard to finish from here.

Comment: Added the promised code samples in the original answer.

Comment: Although your solution seems correct and should work theoretically, it didn't work with me.

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef Can you tell me exactly what is not working? Did you hook in all the mentioned functions or just the one showed in the code sample?

Comment: I think hooking was done successfully as you described, but the wired thing is that it is not responding to `SendMessage` when it is focused.

Comment: Well, sorry but i have no more idea why is it not working.

After setting the hooks and sending the messages the game should think it is the foreground process. At least in my case it worked, you can try to disassemble it and see what methods does it call.

If you are trying to do something which needsd the key to be pressed constantly then you should also take care of the "GetKeyState" function. What i did was to make a shared memory between the processes, and my hook on the GetKeyState reads that memory to know which keys are pressed by my 'bot'.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, the only solution I have found till now, is to bring each other background window to foreground using `SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);`, then press the required keys using `SendInput(uint nInputs, Input[] pInputs, int cbSize);`. However, I am still looking for a better solution to do this without bringing any window to foreground [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613401/how-can-i-send-keys-to-inactive-directx-epsxe-window).

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: I started working on ahk and is working background. But there are timing problems. Maybe you could use it. https://www.codepile.net/pile/KQONpJdq

Comment: Can you describe this timing problems?

Comment: you need to check how long the button is pressed.