# How to use SendInput key_down and key_up events without blocking thread?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, sendinput

I'm sending keys to a game. It works well but that i use thread.sleep blocks thread so i couldn't send keys from actual keyboard spams along code runs belong:

```
Keyboard.SendKey(Keyboard.DirectXKeyStrokes.DIK_2,false,Keyboard.InputType.Keyboard);
Thread.Sleep(100);
Keyboard.SendKey(Keyboard.DirectXKeyStrokes.DIK_2, true, Keyboard.InputType.Keyboard);
Thread.Sleep(100);
...(repeat something like that 20-30x)
```

Keyboard class comes from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55673116/3565914) (it uses SendInput key down and key up events.)

But if i run this, it blocks hardware keyboard inputs. How to run this and other key strokes async or parallel. If i don't use thread.sleep it doesn't work in the game so i should use it. But how can i achieve this without blocking sendinput thread?

> EDIT-1: It's a WPF app. But it doesn't matter WPF or Windows Forms
> app. Because i am trying to make a macro and it's been triggering by a
> play/pause key. I also use a global keyboard hook (low level) so i catch
> play/pause keys.
>
> EDIT-2: If i don't use any delay between key down and up, the game
> doesn't recognize key pressing. Also Key strokes has a sequance and
> the sequance has different delays (key_2 100ms, key_3 500ms, key_a
> 200ms etc).
>
> EDIT-3: Key strokes must be inputs instead messages. Because the game recognize > messages as a text and do not run skill functions. So i use SendInput instead
> PostMessages.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: What is it that you try to achive with the `Thread.Sleep()`, so why not just send all keys at once?

Comment: In which context runs your application (i.e. console, WPF, WinForms, Unity, ...)? Could you maybe use `async/await`? If so you just can use `await Task.Delay(100)`

Comment: WPF. but it doesn't matter forms or wpf. I am trying to make a basic macro. Global keyboard hook that i use and if i catch a trigger key pres in game then i start spam these key strokes.

Comment: If i don't use Thread.Sleep then the game doesn't get the key strokes. So i should add a delay so game can understand what to do. I've tried w/ and w/o. So i can say that it's not working without thread.sleep/delay

Comment: What about the `async/await`? 
Is this part of some event handling?