# C#: Why programmatically pressing keyboard shortcuts doesn't work in all windows?

Tags: c#, winapi, user32

There is a code that, when a certain key/key combination is pressed, programmatically presses the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *(Select text in line)*.

---

**Problem:**

Everything works fine in *notepad, browser, command-line* and other windows, but does not work with text fields in games *(eg `Dota 2`, `CS:GO`)*.

That is, when I press <kbd>G</kbd> *(button to call <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)* nothing happens at all. In this case, the function of pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is called, that is, the <kbd>G</kbd> key is not intercepted by the game.

---

**Python solution**

One way or another, for example, this `Python` code works fine **both in the browser and in the game**, without even intercepting the key from other programs:

```py
import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey('G', callback=lambda: keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+a'))
keyboard.wait()
```

As far as I know, it also refers to `user32.dll`, but why does it work, but not in `C#` - I don't understand.

Here is the source of the function [**`keyboard.press_and_release()`**](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/__init__.py) (line 477) which refers to the `send()` function.

---

**Code:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // when you press the G button, the program will press CTRL+A
            NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyManager.Current.AddOrReplace("G", Key.G, ModifierKeys.None, (sender, e) => { PressCtrlA(sender, e); });
        }

        // method to wait for all keyboard keys to be released
        // to programmatically press CTRL+A to work correctly
        private static readonly Key[] keys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)).Cast<Key>().Where(key => key != Key.None).ToArray();
        private async Task WaitForKeysReleaseAsync()
        {
            int threshold = 0;
            while (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.None || keys.Any(key => Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key)))
            {
                if (threshold++ == 100) // ~5 seconds
                    throw new TimeoutException("Keyboard release timed out or stuck keys");
                await Task.Delay(50);
            }
        }

        // wait until the keyboard is free and press CTRL+A
        private async void PressCtrlA(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await WaitForKeysReleaseAsync();
            KeyboardManager.PressHotkey(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control);
        }
    }
}
```

**The code uses the `KeyboardManager` class to programmatically press keys, here is the code from it: https://pastebin.com/xRtv3drq**

The package `NHotkey.Wpf` is also used.

Comment: <s>Ctrl+A to select all text? Does this work if you press it manually? It might be that the game text fields just don't recognize the key combination.</s>

Comment: @Raphael yes, it works if i click manually.  I also gave an example of a `Python` program that does what I need without even intercepting the `G` key, that is, when text is selected, it is written in the input field.  At the same time, my `C#` script works correctly with other windows

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Snippet uses `SendInput` function, but python code uses `keybd_event`. From description seems like `keybd_event` is lesser level and allows to bypass some restrictions of `SendInput`. Maybe tagging `winapi` can help find people who know answer

Comment: I think its because wpf application. Try this in Winform application.

Comment: @OnurGelmez what's the difference between WPF and Winforms in this context?

Comment: @JL0PD I tried using `keybd_event` - the problem remained: it works everywhere except games. https://pastebin.com/ng4WNKMn

Comment: @denisnumb I had the same exception before I tried on winform and it works but I don't know what is causing that

Comment: @OnurGelmez understood. Anyway, I already tried WinForms and the problem still didn't go away :(

Comment: @jl0 `keybd_event` and `SendInput` inject input at the *exact* same place in the input processing pipeline. There aren't any restrictions with `SendInput` that aren't present with `keybd_event`.

Comment: In my experience with this issue in C, using `SendInput` you can simulate a key press the usual way, or with scan code. When I tried it the usual way, it didn't work in games, just like in your case. When I tried it with a scan code, it worked. Not sure how to do it in C# though but if there is no C# class to handle it, you can make one and use `DllImport`.

Comment: You should look to 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/55673116/6619426'. Maybe it causes error because of DirectX.

Comment: @OnurGelmez yes it worked for me!  Post as an answer please :)